# How is your score calculated in a climb?

Tags: slay-the-spire

I am enjoying the daily climbs in Slay The Spire and would like to get on the first page of the leaderboard. Some of the scoring is obvious (points per enemy, elite & boss), but other scores are less obvious. It seems there are hidden mini achievements in a run that grant points. Is there a list of these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When playing slay the spire, at the end of the run you're awarded a score which, when I first played STS appeared to be extremely arbitrary, however, if you have a deeper look into it you'll find they just use an overly complex score system based on what you do during the run.

Looking at the [WIKI](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Score) they do a good job breaking down the scoring system

```
Name                   Description                                      Score
Floors Climbed         Number of the Floor you reached                  5 per floor
Enemies Killed         For each normal encounter defeated               2 per enemy
Exordium Elites        Killed   For each killed Elite in the Exordium   10 per Elite
City Elites Killed     For each killed Elite in the City                20 per Elite
Beyond Elites Killed   For each killed Elite in the Beyond              30 per Elite
Bosses Slain           For each defeated Boss                           50+ per Boss
Ascension              5% score per Ascension level                     5% per level
Champion               Defeat an Elite without taking damage            25 per Elite
Perfect                Defeat a Boss without taking damage              50 per Boss
Beyond Perfect         Defeat 3 bosses without taking damage            200
Heartbreaker           Defeat the Heart.                                250
Collector              Have 4 copies of any non-starter card            25 per set
Librarian              Deck size greater than 35 cards                  25
Encyclopedian          Deck size greater than 50 cards                  50
Overkill               Deal 99 damage with a single attack              25
Mystery machine        Traveled to 15+ ? rooms                          25
I Like Shiny           Have 25 or more relics                           50
Well Fed               Increased your Max HP by 15 or more              25
Stuffed                Increased your Max HP by 30 or more              50
Money Money            Accrued 1,000 or more gold                       25
Raining Money          Accrued 2,000 or more gold                       50
I Like Gold            Accrued 3,000 or more gold                       75
C-c-c-combo            Play 20 cards in a single turn                   25
Pauper                 Have 0 rare cards                                50
Speedster              Victory in under 60 minutes                      25
Light Speed            Victory in under 45 minutes                      50
Curses!                Your deck contains 5 curses                      100
Highlander             Your deck contains no duplicates                 100
On My Own Terms        Killed yourself                                  50
Poopy                  Received the Spirit Poop                         (-1)
```

However, important to note some will override one another, for example

> Beyond Perfect will override Perfect
>
> Encyclopedian will override Librarian
>
> Stuffed will override Well Fed
>
> Light Speed will override Speedster